# Executing query on AIX causing a hang

Tags: sql, windows, oracle, aix

I have a server application that runs on Windows and AIX, when the client application connects to the instance running on Windows and executes a report which sends a query to the server side, everything goes fine, but when the client application connects to the server instance running on AIX and executes the same report which sends the same query to the server side, the application hangs.

After investigation, I found that the query is causing the hang, because I ran the query directly from command line on AIX using sqlplus, and it did hang also.

I have to note that the DB is Oracle that running on a different machine that had Windows Server.

The query I am talking about is:

```
select z_name, s_date,
        n_count, f_count, m_count, s_count, d_count, a_count,
        (n_count + f_count + m_count + s_count + d_count + a_count) as d_total
from
(select z_name, s_date,
          nvl((select s_count from vReport S1 where S1.z_id = S.z_id and S1.s_date = S.s_date and s_app = 'NC'), 0) as n_c_count,
          nvl((select s_count from vReport S1 where S1.z_id = S.z_id and S1.s_date = S.s_date and s_app = 'FS'), 0) as f_s_count,
          nvl((select s_count from vReport S1 where S1.z_id = S.z_id and S1.s_date = S.s_date and s_app = 'MC'), 0) as m_c_count,
          nvl((select s_count from vReport S1 where S1.z_id = S.z_id and S1.s_date = S.s_date and s_app like 'SAA %'), 0) as s_c_count,
          nvl((select s_count from vReport S1 where S1.z_id = S.z_id and S1.s_date = S.s_date and s_app = 'DC'), 0) as d_c_count,
          nvl((select s_count from vReport S1 where S1.z_id = S.z_id and S1.s_date = S.s_date and s_app = 'SA'), 0) as a_c_count,
          nvl((select sum(s_count) from vReport S1 where S1.z_id = S.z_id), 0) as d_total
from rvReport S
where s_date between TO_DATE('2012-08-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and  TO_DATE('2012-08-02 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
and  z_id in (3,61,41,21) 
union 
select distinct z_name, SYSDATE,
          nvl((select sum(s_count) from vReport S1 where S1.z_id = S.z_id and s_app = 'NC' and s_date between TO_DATE('2012-08-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and  TO_DATE('2012-08-02 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')), 0) as n_c_count,
          nvl((select sum(s_count) from vReport S1 where S1.z_id = S.z_id and s_app = 'FS' and s_date between TO_DATE('2012-08-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and  TO_DATE('2012-08-02 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')), 0) as f_s_count,
          nvl((select sum(s_count) from vReport S1 where S1.z_id = S.z_id and s_app = 'MC' and s_date between TO_DATE('2012-08-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and  TO_DATE('2012-08-02 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')), 0) as m_c_count,
          nvl((select sum(s_count) from vReport S1 where S1.z_id = S.z_id and s_app like 'SAA %' and s_date between TO_DATE('2012-08-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and  TO_DATE('2012-08-02 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')), 0) as s_c_count,
          nvl((select sum(s_count) from vReport S1 where S1.z_id = S.z_id and s_app = 'DC' and s_date between TO_DATE('2012-08-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and  TO_DATE('2012-08-02 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')), 0) as d_c_count,
          nvl((select sum(s_count) from vReport S1 where S1.z_id = S.z_id and s_app = 'SA' and s_date between TO_DATE('2012-08-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and  TO_DATE('2012-08-02 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')), 0) as a_c_count,
          nvl((select sum(s_count) from vStats S1 where S1.z_id = S.zone_id  and s_date between TO_DATE('2012-08-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and  TO_DATE('2012-08-02 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')), 0) as z_total
from rvReport S
where s_date between TO_DATE('2012-08-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and  TO_DATE('2012-08-02 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
and z_id in (3,61,41,21)
) STEMP
```

Note: I forgot to say that, if the condition "and z_id in (3,61,41,21)" in the select statement after the union is removed, the query will be executed on AIX and won't hang but will return wrong data.

Comment: Do you have the same table structures, indexes and data volumes on both servers? Are the statistics up-to-date on both? Can you obtain and compare the explain plan or execution plan for both?

Comment: Well, the 2 server instances connect to the same DB which runs on another machine which has Windows Server. And I don't know about the other questions you asked because I am not a DB expert, but if you told me how to obtain them, I mean the statistics and both plans you talked about, I can give it a try.